# Is there a way to make it so Tor doesn't repeat the same IP or gives the same IP less often?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

I noticed that sometimes when I connect with Tor or get a new identity, I'll see an IP repeated. Is there any way to make it so Tor never repeats the same IP or gives the same IP less often? Or is there some way to add additional IP's to Tor so it has more it can connect to? Thanks.

Comment: The best way to add additional exit nodes is to run your own! Alternatively you could support [one of these organisations](http://www.torservers.net/partners.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this would reduce your anonimity and make you more likely to be fingerprinted.

Comment: WHICH reduces anonymity?  Running a node, or not repeating an IP, or supporting an organization?  I think "never repeating an IP" would be difficult (and someday there would be none left).  But it seems to me feasible and worthwhile for Tor to keep a list of the last N<10 exit nodes used and not use one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many hundreds of Tor exit nodes you may get when choosing New Identity, each exit node of course with its own IP address. However, since not all Tor exit nodes is equally fast, Tor select the faster ones more often than the slow ones. This is necessary to avoid overloading the slow nodes, when capacity is available on the fast ones, but creates the problem that you are much likelier to get certain nodes (and therefore certain IP addresses) as exits.

I assume that you want another IP address because you are trying to evade IP blocking. In this case there is unfortunately not any feasible way to avoid getting the same IP address again, other than keep trying New Identity again.

If you absolutely want to ban one IP address so it never is selected, I believe this is possible to do by editing Tors configuration file. I do not know how to, and it is not recommended as it decreases your anonymity.

You cannot add more IP addresses Tor chooses from (short of running your own Tor exit servers). Tor already chooses among all available.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add additional IPs but you can limit some tor servers on the basis of ip address or country code.
edit your torrc file and write there:

```
ExcludeExitNodes someIPaddress 
StrictNodes 1
```

it will exclude that IP address, if you want to block then whole country:

```
ExcludeExitNodes {de},{at},{fr}
```

if you want to choose country:

```
ExitNodes {us},{ca}
```

this means your exit nodes will be only from america and canada. you can choose also entry nodes:

```
EntryNodes {au},{ru}
ExitNodes {us},{pl}
StrictNodes 1
```

you understand already that entry will be from australia and russia and exit nodes from usa and poland.

of course, if you want to exclude some nodes from entry and exit:

```
ExcludeNodes someIPaddress or CountryCode
Strict1
```

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en